# jupyter notebooks not displaying or behaving correctly on Pycharm remote development with WSL2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

This is a tricky one... I am trying to run my pycharm projects remotely with a client on windows 11 and the environment in ubuntu on WSL2 (all good with that part). My problem happens when I create or open a jupyter notebook in a remote project. I get the following screen:
[image: the screen]

The expected is:
[image: Correct behaviour]

as shown on screenshot, my environment is missing lots of components, like the cell toolbars, editor gutter, and the worst part... the cell result. So, if I execute a cell through the notebook toolbar (that one is actually displayed) I get no cell results. If I open the notebook server, all is good... Am I doing something stupid or is it a pyCharm bug? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What PyCharm version are you using? What happens when you click "Trusted"? as your second image shows? And not clear what you mean by "remote" when I see `localhost:8888` in the toolbar

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried on 2023.2.1 and 2023.1.4 same behavior on both... it IS the localhost on the remote machine. I am using WSL2 as the development environment and executing the client locally. Clicking on trusted changes nothing (it just sets the kernel as trusted for the jupyter server)

Comment: I guess I am confused what you mean by "using WSL2" when you have a native Windows IDE window open. You are running Python in WSL2 instead of natively in Windows?

Comment: Yep... I know :) I have in my local Windows a WSL2 Ubuntu environment. I am configuring it for development as I don't want to install Anaconda and all the development dependecies on my windows. Not only that, I much rather use the linux terminal for development. Pm pycharm (professional) we have an option for remote development on WSL environment (that would be AWESOME if it worked). my objective is to segregate the environments and keep all the development tools on the WSL2 part of my system.

Comment: I even have a bug opened with jetbrains, but they take a long time to even assess it.

Comment: But if you install just Python (not Anaconda), then does the UI look like what you want? In other words, maybe it is the remote connection that is the issue? Because you need to port-forward the WSL2 hypervisor otherwise

Comment: Might work, but really defies the purpose. I want to segregate the environments. I think If I install it locally it will work, but the whole point is to try and make it work remotely.
TY @OneCricketeer for making me think a little bit more about the whole planned workflow..  :) might need to change it, but had really high hopes for this WSL remote development from Pycharm :(